# recursive query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

[image: table 'users']

and I have the following query:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE users_r AS (
          SELECT user_id, parent_id, 0 as level
          FROM users
          WHERE parent_id is null
        UNION ALL
          SELECT u.user_id, u.parent_id, u.level + 1
          FROM users u
              INNER JOIN users_r
                  ON (u.parent_id = users_r.user_id)   
    )

    SELECT * FROM users_r LIMIT 1000
```

I want to fill "level" column with depending on the count of ancestors. But my code isn't working. It fills rows only where parent_id is null.

[image: Result of my code]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple typo.

The recursive `SELECT`, immediately after the `UNION ALL` should not read

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.parent_id, u.level + 1
```

but

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.parent_id, users_r.level + 1
```

You would have noticed right away if you didn't have a `level` column in `users`.